# jquery trigger on certain item state conditions

Tags: jquery

Looking to trigger an action but not sure what the best way to go about it is. Still picking up jquery / javascript, so thought I'd ask for advice before hacking something out.

Have a unordered list of items with a toggle(two buttons) on each item. Once they have all been toggled, if they're all A do something, if at least one of them is B do something different.

Looking to not bog down the interface speed so looking for a speedy way. I guess I would have to do it on every button press regardless? Was thinking i could just bind it to the last item, but that may not always be the last one processed.

was also thinking I could set something like a string with "ABC" and after each item is updated it removes it's particular letter from the string then executes a function if the string is empty.

Am I over thinking? From what I've read you need to be careful with how you select elements with jquery because some things like selecting by ID are much speedier than others.

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<li id="1"> 
    <h3 class="item_id">#17A</h3> 
    <div class="itemstatus">
        <span class="itemstate">Pending</span>
        <span class="statereason"></span>
    </div>
    <p>cheese</p>
    <span class="btns">
        <a href="#" class="greenButton" id="approve">True</a> 
        <a href="#" class="redButton" id="decline">False</a>
    </span> 
</li>
```

status of each item is presently determined via the itemstate span contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to have your `li`s store the value for each of their states in the class attribute. Then as these states get updated, run a function to check the numbers for each of the different states.

I've set up a working demo at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/fCWvc/1/).

I'd suggest that all your `li`s start off by having the attribute `class="unknown"` so you're able to track states that have yet to be updated.

```
<li id="1" class="unknown">
```

Your jQuery code will look something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var CheckAllStates = function(){

        var unknownCount = $('ul#myList li.unknown').length;
        var greenCount = $('ul#myList li.green').length;
        var redCount = $('ul#myList li.red').length;
        var totalCount = unknownCount + greenCount + redCount ;

        if (unknownCount == 0)
        {
            if (greenCount == totalCount)
            {
                alert ('All greens');
            }
            else if (redCount >= 1)
            {
                alert('At least one red');    
            }
        }
    };

    $('ul#myList a.greenButton').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').attr('class', 'green');
        CheckAllStates();
    });

    $('ul#myList a.redButton').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').attr('class', 'red');
       CheckAllStates();
    });

    $('input#reset').click(function(){
        $('ul#myList li').attr('class', 'unknown');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's along the lines of what i was thinking, but i didn't think to check length of selections like that. I would have done something much more intensive - and unnecessary. Thank you!

Comment: @meesterfox - No worries, I've actually updated the code with something that matches your requirements a little more closely. Check it at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/fCWvc/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the same event handler to each button press.  In that event handler, you just check the state of all the buttons.  If all are set, process them and pick your action based on their settings.

If you show us the actual HTML and assign appropriate classes and ids to be able to iterate through the buttons, we could advise on the jQuery that would make it easy.

After modifying your HTML a bit (to add some more useful classes), I came up with this code:

```
$("#questions .toggle").click(function() {
    // turn this button on, make sure other paired button is off
    $(this).addClass("pressed").siblings().removeClass("pressed");

    // check all buttons to see if each set has a chosen button
    var missingSelection = false;
    var allGreen = true;
    $("#questions .btns").each(function() {
        var pressed$ = $(this).find(".pressed");
        if (pressed$.length == 0) {
            missingSelection = true;
        } else {
            if (!pressed$.hasClass("greenButton")) {
                allGreen = false;
            }
        }
    });
    if (!missingSelection) {
        if (allGreen) {
            // code when all buttons are green
            $("#result").html("All Buttons Green");
        } else {
            // code when any buttons is not green
            $("#result").html("Some Buttons Not Green");
        }
    }

    // stop any further processing of the click
    return(false);
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ctjxw/

FYI, I also had to remove conflicting ID values and remove ID values that start with a number.

Comment: presently what gets changed is the itemstate span, from pending to true or false. There will be a number of them so looking up each span state seemed like it might be too much. 
 
`<li id="1">
                      <h3 class="item_id">#17A</h3>
                      <div class="itemstatus"><span class="itemstate">Pending</span><span class="statereason"></span></div>
                      <p>cheese</p>
                      <span class="btns"><a href="#" class="greenButton" id="approve">True</a> <a href="#" class="redButton" id="decline">False</a></span>
                    </li>`

Comment: I copied your HTML into your question.  Comments simply don't work for multi-line HTML or javascript so you should generally put them in your question using the Edit button.

Comment: I added a jQuery solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking the performance aspect of this right now. When you're just picking up a new technology, it's better to aim for clear, readable code that does the job. You can optimize for speed later if performance becomes an issue. You'll be more experienced and know what to fix at that point. :)

That being said, there are some things that you'll learn pretty quickly that are just Good Ideas™:

- If you're going to be running through a list of items repeatedly, perform your select once, then assign the resulting list to a variable that is scoped outside of your click handler function. That way you're not rerunning the select every time your click handler executes.
- It's better to avoid storing application state in the DOM, i.e. applying custom classes to elements so that later you can tell if they've been clicked. I would first try mapping the buttons to an array of values that you could store in a variable. Storing app state in the DOM gets complicated very quickly.
- If you're going to store application state in the DOM, I'd recommend using `data-` attributes rather than applying custom classes.
- If your app is going to be complex, it might be worth the investment to learn a JavaScript application framework like Backbone.js. These frameworks handle a lot of the details of updating the display when the user changes some data or performs an action. There's definitely a learning curve here, though.

Comment: well hrm. I mean I need to store the values anyway, and need to show it anyway... I guess I'm a little fuzzy on javascript persistence of data. I'm actually doing this in jqtouch, so it's stacks of divs and one page in code, with ajax calls to an api to fetch new data and send data to the server.

what would be good reason to use backbone, simply app complexity? I'm not sure where my app's complexity falls. doesn't feel that complex...

I'll have to checkout the data attributes though, probably easier to get at. 

thank you otherwise. good advice.